Are Nikon N90s parts compatible with a Nikon Coolpix L810?
I was able to obtain a Nikon n90s camera with multiple lense attachments (Aspherical LD Tamron and a Hoya 58mm Skylight (18) by Vivitar I think) two flash attachments, and a MD-15 Motor drive.  Would either lense fit on a Nikon Coolpix L810?

Only one is a lens (The Tamron Aspherical LD), the other is a spin-on filter that attaches to the front of lenses with 58mm filter threads. Your CoolPix L810 doesn't accept any  interchangeable lenses (because the one it has is not removeable) and has no filter threads of any size. It has no way to control an external flash and doesn't use film. So none of that stuff would be usable with the L810.
